# Can Selenium Library / Selenium RC be used to spam online forms which lack human authentication tests?

Tags: forms, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, spam, bots

I have been using Selenium Library with Robot Framework for writing automated tests for web applications, I know most browsers have some degree of protection against automated scripts but is it possible to make spam bots, particularly for spamming online forms which lack captchas or other human user verification checks ?

PS: Just curious ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those would be exceptionally uneffective (slow and heavyweight), but yes, Selenium could be possibly used in such a way. With in-memory HtmlUnitDriver (which doesn't open a browser window), it could also run somewhere undetected for ages.